# Block passing Gestures to SuperView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uipangesturerecognizer

A ScrollView is there with some SubViews....
ScrollView Contains its predefined gestures(Pan) and my custom gesture(Pan) as well and Recognize it simultaneously...
SubViews also contains custom Pan Gesture......
Everything is working fine except pan gesture on SubViews ...
When i am doing pan on SubView its SuperView also getting touches and handling that which i don't want...
When pan is being done on the subViews, the superView Should not recognize them...
How i Can Block passing my SubView gesture to its SuperView?

Answer (score 9):

To block superview from responding to gesture, when there is subview under the touch point can be done as follows:

Implement the following method of UIGestureDelegate

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch;
```

as

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return  (touch.view == superView);
}
```

and set this delegate to gestureRecognizer assigned to superView.

I hope that this should do the needed.

Comment: For me, I had to tick 'User interaction enabled' in the subview to make it work, but it did.

Answer (score 0):

basically when you click on subview then superview gestures are not recognized because your superview overlapped by subview .

Add delegate in .h and give it to tapGestures and give the condition like this

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if([gestureRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[superView class]])
        return NO;
    else
        return YES;
}
```

Comment: yes that is what suppose to happened...but in this case its not happening....when i remove the simultaneous gesture recognization of superview then it works as expected.....any idea what could be the catch?

Comment: for that you'l take condition and check if that one coming from superview then do nothing.